# how to reference entry point in an external dll (C# / unity 3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, serial-port

I am using Unity 3D for an application I need to use Serial Port but in Unity, there's a missing implementation of event `DataReceived` and others linked functions.
Therefore I think the solution is to make my own DLL that can manage Serial Port data and call it from unity as an external DLL.

I wrote the code below. the code in my class library project (just a serial port froze opening for the test)

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace serialPortManager2
{
    public class laserManager
    {
        private SerialPort laserComPort;

        public bool  open()
        {
            bool laserSerialPortDetected = false;
            // ouverture du port série pour pilotage du laser
            foreach (string portName in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                if (portName == "COM4") laserSerialPortDetected = true;
            }
            if (laserSerialPortDetected)
            {
                laserComPort = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                laserComPort.Open();
                if (laserComPort.IsOpen)
                {
                    // timeout de lecture d'une mesure laser
                    laserComPort.ReadTimeout = 5000;
                    return true;
                }
                else return false;
            }
            else return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Code to reference DLL in Unity:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public static class SPNativePlugIn {

// The name of the external library containing the native functions
private const string LIBRARY_NAME = "serialPortManager2";

[DllImport(LIBRARY_NAME)] public static extern bool open();

}
```

My problem is that I get this error: `EntryPointNotFoundException: open`

I guess I have to integrate the `laserManager` class somewhere but I do not know the syntax, I tried quite a few things but I can not find it.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the following links: 1)https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VisualStudioIntegration.html
2)https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-import-my-own-c-classes-into-another-c-script.64120/

Comment: Thx for your answer. However i can't import my C# script in Unity because the problem is that Unity don't implement some functions around DataReceived event, so i suppose i need to use a compiled dll outside of unity3D.

Comment: I also wonder if the pb could not come from the external dll I created. Is it possible to create a class library (.NET framework) and call the methods as in a c ++ library? Is there a particular option to validate in visual studio?
Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named "Plugins" in the "Assets" Folder then put your .dll file in the "Plugins" folder and import it in your script in this way
 `using dllFileName;`

This works for every  .dll not include in the unity default library

Comment: Sorry i pressed enter by mistake. My dll name is serialPortManager.dll it's a c# class Library. Ok i put it in folder "Plugins" Under Assets folder ans in my code i wrote "using serialPortManager" however i have this error : nameSpace "serialPortManager" not found.   I tried to put also laserManager.cs (witch is a class of serialPortManager) in a folder scripts Under Assets. It works but unity use is own compilation so the missing serialPort function (bytesToRead) still does not work.  Any idea ?

Comment: have  you add `using serialPortManager2;` as namespace to your code too ?

Comment: Finally I understood my mistake but that does not solve my problem.
The namespace not found was related to the fact that the dll was compiled for a .NET> 2.0. Now Unity accepts the dll.
On the other hand I am trying to make from the beginning to replace a function that does not work in unity by calling an equivalent function of an external dll does not work either. Replacing serialPort.BytesToRead by serialPortManager.BytesToRead have the same result:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object